I have a variational calculus Formula 1 problem that I can't find the answer to anywhere
I've asked this problem to various professors, as well as looking online and in books for help, but since I made it up I can't seem to find anything, and I don't think I have the skills required for it yet. Here it goes:
Imagine an F1 racing track in two dimensions that can be described by a parametric surface of the form $\sigma(t, u)=\langle f_1(t,u),f_2(t,u)\rangle$ which complies with the requisites that the parameter $t$ is used to give it direction (like, the curve shape) like in any parametric curve, and the parameter $u$ is just used to give it a certain thickness.
Now, what would be the geodesic, or the shortest path, between any two points on that surface? The resulting curve should be a continuos $C^1$ or $C^2$ curve so a "car" could run it without suddenly changing velocities or acceleration.
The problem here is that I can only find the techniques used in variational calculus for geodesics in 3d geometries, while here we are constrained to a surface that its itself inside a plane; while the geodesic on a plane is a straight line, the 2d geometry of the race track doesn't necessarily comply with that because of the way it might curve (the straight line might go out of the borders and that's not allowed). I tried to use the Lagrange multipliers method but I could not find a way where I could split the cases since that doesn't result in the optimum path.
To give the simplest example which I've been trying to work on, consider the parametric surface of the form $$\sigma(r,\theta)=\langle r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)\rangle$$ with the non-holonomic constraints $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\frac{1}{2}\le r\le{3\over 2}$. This is basically a disc with inner radius 0.5 and outer radius 1.5. The goal is to find the geodesic between any two points $(r_0,\theta_0)$ and $(r_1,\theta_1)$ that are within the constraints. Notice how with close up points the geodesic might be a straight line because the border of the race track is not interfering with it so its just like a regular plane? But also, if the points are further apart, like on opposite sides of the disk, the curve is totally different.
How would one solve this? I'm a physics student from 5th semester and I'm taking a classical mechanics class that uses the Goldstein as its textbook, so all my variational calculus skills come from there, as well as a Vector calculus course I took last semester.

I think doing calculus of variations with this kind of inequality constraint ("particle must lie between boundaries of track") is complicated in general and isn't usually relevant for physics. I did find some math SE questions you might find interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227469/what-would-be-the-shortest-path-between-2-points-when-there-are-objects-obstruct, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613613/calculus-of-variation-with-inequality-constraints, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844365/closed-geodesic-on-a-non-simply-connected-riemannian-manifold

Also: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/036CAFC7D64E7C17F4B161010AD5EF9D/S0008414X00024391a.pdf/inequality-constraints-in-the-calculus-of-variations.pdf
